# Color Segmentation: A better cluster-analysis to find K

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, computer-vision, cluster-analysis, k-means

I know there have been many questions such as this and some solutions to them, but I'm hoping there's another way.

**GOAL:** The final goal is to cluster colors given an image, then allow the user to change those colors. The user does not need to enter any k. The algorithm determines **K**.

**METHOD:** Currently, I'm using the silhouette score metric (http://scikit-learn.sourceforge.net/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.silhouette_score.html#sklearn.metrics.silhouette_score). I'm using MiniBatchKMeans to cluster the image and then calculate the silhouette_score within a range of k (4-8). The code would be:

```
# silhouetteCoeff determination
def silhouetteCoeff(z):
max_silhouette = 0
max_k = 0
for i in range(4, 17):
    clt = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters = i, random_state = 42)
    clt.fit(z)
    silhouette_avg = silhouette_score(z, clt.labels_, sample_size = 250, random_state = 42)
    print("k: ", i, " silhouette avg: ", silhouette_avg)
    if (silhouette_avg == 1.0):
        max_k = i
        break
    elif (silhouette_avg > max_silhouette):
        max_silhouette = silhouette_avg
        max_k = i
print("Max silhouette: ", max_silhouette)
print("Max k: ", max_k)
return int(max_k)
```

Even if I color quantize the image beforehand (to 16 colors), the function still takes a good 6-8 seconds to run (assume image size 400x400).

My question is, is there any **better or faster** way to find k? I've tried the **Elbow method** too, but still gotta calculate the SSE there. From testing on some images, I've found a good average k = 8. But on a more color intensive image, the algorithm loses out on some colors.

Answer (score 0):

Measure your bottleneck!

Silhouette is in O(n²) so most likely it will be the bottleneck of your approach. Also, there are much faster k-means variants than the one in sklearn... so there is a lot of potential to make things faster.

Minibatch kmeans won't even converge, but only approximate the result. It only makes sense if you can't afford to keep all data in memory as far as I can tell.

Reducing the color palette to just 16 colors supposedly does not at all help.